# Creating a custom waiting room UI in place of Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent()

Tags: google-play-services

I want to create a custom waiting room UI in my game to replace to default room proposed by Google using Google Play Services, but I not understand how I can do that. I call the Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(getApiClient(), room, MIN_PLAYERS) method when I do a Quick Game. Can anyone help me please? The method is this:

> void showWaitingRoom(Room room) {
>         System.out.println("showWaitingRoom");
>
> ```
>     // minimum number of players required for our game
>     // For simplicity, we require everyone to join the game before we start it
>     // (this is signaled by Integer.MAX_VALUE).
>     final int MIN_PLAYERS = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
>     Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(getApiClient(), room,
> ```
>
> MIN_PLAYERS);
>
> ```
>     // show waiting room UI
>     startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
> }
> ```

Sorry for the English, but I'm Italian. Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

The getWaitingRoomIntent is for the default UI, if you want a custom UI just don't call that and build your own UI from data received in the OnPeerJoined and other callbacks of RoomStatusUpdateListener.